# How to use each file from uploaded multiple files in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I upload multiple files using shiny but how i use each of them?

here is a short script that i write, this does'nt work:

```
 output$NewDataPlot<-renderPrint({

  DataSets <- input$newfile
  for(p in 1:length(DataSets)){

    DataSet<-read.delim(**DataSets[p]**,header = TRUE,row.names = 1,sep="\t",blank.lines.skip=TRUE)##Read specific dataset

    ##Cut the genes that at least 80% of their expresions is lower then 10
    delete<-0
    for(i in 1:length(DataSet[,1])){
     count<-0
       for(j in 1:length(DataSet[i,])){
        if(DataSet[2,3]<10 || DataSet[2,3]=="" || DataSet[2,3]==" "){
          count=count+1
          cat(count,i,j,DataSet[i,j])
        }
      }

      if(count>0.8*length(DataSet[i,])){
        DataSet=DataSet[-i,]
        delete<-delete+1
     }
    }
```

)}
ui is written in html:

```
    <input id="newfile" type="file" multiple accept="text/csv,text/comma-separated-    values,text/plain,.csv"  />
    <input id="newGOI" type="file" accept="text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/plain,.csv"  />
```

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#uploads)? Try running shiny::runExample("09_upload") If that works, look at the [example code](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/master/inst/examples/09_upload) and try adapting it to your needs. I would suggest storing the data in a [reactiveValues](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/reactiveValues) and then calling and processing each one in your function.